# phpgmailer set from mail issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to use php mail class as shown in the example.

http://www.vulgarisoip.com/category/phpgmailer/

I'm using it my site's contact us form. Can I set the "$mail->From" address as the person who filled the form? When i reveive the mail it always shows that the "from address" as my gmail account. Any help would really helpful.

```
<?php
require_once('phpgmailer/class.phpgmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPGMailer();
$mail->Username = 'username@gmail.com'; 
$mail->Password = 'gmailpassword';
$mail->From = 'from@hotmail.com'; // Like to set this address as the address of the person who filled the form
$mail->FromName = 'User Name';
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';
$mail->AddAddress('myname@mydomain.com'); // To which address the mail to be delivered
$mail->Body = 'Hey buddy, heres an email!';
$mail->Send();


?>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Allow a user to specify a from: address only simplifies spamming.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->From = $_POST['from'];
```

or what ever the field is named

Answer (score 0):

Gmail uses the authenticated account as the sender to cut down on address spoofing and spam. No matter what you set as the from address, Gmail will auto set it to your gmail user.

### UPDATE

Your comment:

> "My intention was actually when I received a mail with the actual
>   sender as "from address", so that I can directly reply to him."

You may want to try:

```
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, $display_name);
```

Comment: ok Thanks for the info. My intention was actually when I received a mail with the actual sender as "from address", so that I can directly reply to him. That's all. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, in that case; you may want to try: $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $display_name);